# Solving for x in a Normal Distribution problem envolving addition of two normal distributions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have this problem envolving normal distribution:

Consider 2 normal distributions that describe the daily waste of a family in city A and city B, respetively:

**A~N(11.5;2.5^2)**

**B~N(9;3^2)**

Mean and variance are in kilograms.

In 18.51% of the days, the families from city B produce waste that exceeds in over "x" kilograms the amount of waste produced by the families in city A.

Find x.

This is what i came up with:

**P(B+x>A)=0.1851**

**P(B+x-A>0)=0.1851**

with

**B+x-A ~ N(-2.5+x;3.91^2)**

using z-score:

**1-P(Z<0)=0.1851**

with

**z=(0-(-2.5+x))/3.91**

i got

**P(Z<0)=0.8149**

**(2.5-x)/3.91=Φ^(-1)(0.8149)**

which gave me

**x=-1.019**

with

**Φ^(-1)(0.8149) =0.9 (aprox.)**

I'm trying to solve this problem and this answer doesn't seem to be the correct one given the context of the problem. I don't know if it's correct to consider only 1 family from each city in my calculations given the problems asks for the total of families, but the problem doesn't give me the total amount of families in each city. I also assume working with one family versus working with all the families is just a matter of proportion that will give the same result. Correct me if my reasoning is wrong.

Where am I making the mistake(s) in this exercice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought you should end up with $$x=(9-11.5) +\Phi^{-1}(1-0.1851) \sqrt{2.5^2 +3^2} \approx +1$$
and your initial error in the sign of $x$ is in trying to consider $\mathbb P(B+x>A)$ when the question is asking about $\mathbb P(B-A > x)=\mathbb P(B-x > A)$